# How to correctly upload photos/files in a Django + Angular decoupled application to S3?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, angular5, angular6

I have a decoupled applications build with Django 2, an API with DRF and an Angular 6 frontend application. I want to enable users to upload photos for their profiles, and probably in the future some pdfs, and after some research I figured out that the most convenient thing to do would be to store these files in an Amazon S3 bucket.

I have found numerous resources about how to upload files to an S3 bucket on both, Angular and Django, and now I was wondering what would be the best approach to do this in my decoupled application: should I manage it on the frontend and not use my backend at all? or should I pass the file from my angular to my Django app and then upload it to the bucket from there?

Some pros and cons of both approaches? It's my first time doing this and I haven't been able to find many resources for decoupled applications.

Any help is welcome! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The best practice

Anything related to data must be managed by your backend i.e Django, Angular is just a client.

> You should pass the file from angular to Django app and then upload it
> to the s3 bucket from there

## Cons using client

Suppose in future, if you will develop mobile apps to consume your rest APIs then you need to rewrite the whole management there also.

You have to keep your s3 bucket API keys on the client and it is easily accessible to hackers.

`dist` folder size will be going to increase that will affect the load time of your site

If you are uploading files from client to S3 bucket, it will use the user's internet and in most of the cases it is slower than your sever's internet